# Good resource for non-Latin character based fonts?

Tags: fonts, resource-recommendations

I was wondering if there were any good resources for fonts using non-Latin characters, specifically Japanese or Chinese type (Kanji or any other character-based font).

I know plenty of resources for Latin based fonts, but not any for other types. There must be a resource out there. I know a google search will help, but that might only get me some scattered results and more importantly I'd love to get some insight from you guys and gals here. If there's any resource like LintoType or WhatTheFont (do these websites have sections for these types of fonts?), that would be wonderful.

[Edit]

The reason I ask is because sometimes I do work that involves Chinese characters and I only have the standard stock fonts that, while nice and readable, just don't have that creative aspect I'm looking for.

[Edit]

This is a pretty nice resource I've found: 
http://www.typebank.co.jp/english/

I just have no idea how to work this site (in regards to buying/downloading).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [Adobe](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?event=displayFontsHome&store=OLS-US&language=EN) and [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/product.aspx?PID=161) have put a lot of resources into CJK font development. The Creative Suites (and InDesign as a standalone product) and Windows 7 ship with several that provide quite a variety of styles among them.

In the [Adobe Font Store](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?event=displayFontsHome&store=OLS-US&language=EN) choose "Classification" from the search menu in the right sidebar. You'll find Chinese, Japanese, etc.

Fonts.com lists [113 Traditional Chinese fonts](http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/searchresults.htm?kid=cjk%20font&classification=Traditional%20Chinese) and [118 Simplified Chinese](http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/searchresults.htm?kid=cjk%20font&classification=Simplified%20Chinese) alone. On their site, choose Find Fonts, then choose Classification. In addition to these two, you'll find Kaku, Mincho, Mandarin and other Asian categories.